# Slack mentions not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webhooks, slack-api, slack

I'm using the slack-notifier gem to send notifications to my slack channel.

```
  notifier = Slack::Notifier.new "https://hooks.slack.com/services/ABC1234567890"
  notifier.ping "Text <@user1>"
```

That is the general setup in rails.

When I send to @user1 (my coworker), everything is OK.

But if I send it to @user2 (myself), text is displayed without mention creating notification or being a clickable link.

Also, if i send it to a usergroup, @my_team text is same above.

I have also tried `!my_team` and `<@user1|user1>` . The output to the slack channel looks like `<my_team>` or `@user1`. So it appears it is not parsing correctly.

Why could this be happening?

Comment: Are you using the friendly name (e.g. `<@smarx>`) or the user ID (e.g. `<@U12345>`)? [The documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting) makes no mention of the former, but in practice it seems to work.

Comment: I'm using the friendly name, how could i find the ID? Specifically for the user group, because that is the end goal.

I just did a test and omitted the <> tags in the string, it is having some success but I don't know why. The notifications arent firing but the name is now highlighted yellow...

Comment: I'd suggest `notifier.ping "Text @user1", parse: "full"`. With `parse=full`, you won't have to bother getting the IDs for things and can just get the parsing behavior you typically expect from manually typing into the Slack client.

Comment: parse: "full" was the solution. Please write it as an answer and I'll select it as such!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Moving my comment to an answer.)

I'd suggest this:

```
notifier.ping "Text @user1", parse: "full"
```

The "full" parse mode means you'll get automatic linking of @username, #channelname, etc., just like you get when typing into the Slack website/clients.